# How to get the original path of a symbolic link in PHP?

Tags: php, path, symlink

I have several files in my web folder, including these two:

- /mydocroot/include/somesubdir/include.inc.php
- /mydocroot/include/settings.inc.php

where **somesubdir** is a symbolic link to another directory on my disk, to a path named, eh, let's say **/anywhere/else**.

Inside **include.inc.php**, something like this is written:

```
<?php

require_once "../settings.inc.php";

?>
```

In my opinion, that *should* include **/mydocroot/include/settings.php**... But guess what happens: PHP tries to include **/anywhere/settings.inc.php**, *instead of* **/mydocroot/include/settings.inc.php**.

It seems like PHP automatically resolves symbolic links.

How can I avoid this and include my **settings.inc.php** file?

Comment: What does `echo __DIR__;` inside `/include.inc.php` print?

Comment: @Rocket: `echo __DIR__;` prints `/anywhere/else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight forward solution is to always use absolute paths.  There are multiple ways you can do this, from hard coding the path every time you need it, to hard coding the path once in the top of your script and referencing that, to dynamically figuring it out and setting it once at the top of your script.

The third option is what most off the shelf CMSs use to be able to run without complete knowledge of your file structure.

Why is it that you're using a symbolically linked directory in this manner?

Comment: You already noted it in your comment to @adam; I indeed use a symbolic link because I don't want to have multiple versions of the same file on my hard disk. It's shared code.

Comment: Fair enough, that's why I asked.  You can still use my answer.  Just set or figure it first, before including `/mydocroot/include/somesubdir/include.inc.php -> /anywhere/else/include.inc.php`.  Perhaps not ideal, but it's all you've got as far as I can tell.

Comment: It seems to be the only way it can be accomplished. This is the way I created the workaround: I created a file (call it **symlink.php**) inside **/mydocroot/include/**, which contains only one statement: `define("ROOT", __DIR__);` Then in **include.inc.php** I check if the constant `ROOT` has been defined or not. If yes, then use that path.

Answer (score 4):

I just had a similar issue. You can do it by using `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` variable, that displays the requested file, so in your case it will be `/mydocroot/include/somesubdir/include.inc.php`, even if `somesubdir` is a symbolic link. To include a file that is one level lower instead of doing

```
require_once "../settings.inc.php";
```

do this:

```
require_once dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."settings.inc.php"
```

[Documentation about `$_SERVER` variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create a basepath variable. The best way to do this is to include the following at the top of your script and then reference it

```
$basepath = dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

You can then reference the basepath in your includes, requires, etc. Therefore,

```
include "../myscript.php";
```

Would become,

```
include $basepath."myscript.php";
```

If you are back ticking further, you will have this:

```
include "../../myscript.php";
```

Would become,

```
include $basepath."../myscript.php";
```

You must nest the dir_name functions twice, plus one more time for each additional folder you need to backtick through. You MUST get all the way back to the folder where the symbolic link exists.

I consider this issue a major design flaw with PHP. I can't think of a single instance where accessing backticked files relative to the actual file would be desirable. In all situations, including virtual hosting, it ONLY makes sense to regress back along the linked path, never the target path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`is_link`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-link.php) to check if a file is a symbolic link. If it is, use [`readlink`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readlink.php) to get the absolute target.

But, in ten years of php development I've never had cause to use symbolic links. As Jason suggests, I've always defined or deduced an absolute path once, then used that throughout my app to make all file paths absolute.

Comment: The problem is that it won't work backwards, the way he's trying to do it.  Essentially, the file in the linked directory has no way of determining that the directory it's in was accessed in a linked context, rather than directly through the literal file system.  As for using symbolic links, it can make sense in limited contexts.  The only way it makes sense in the context of the OP is if the file is being shared among multiple virtual hosts.